# python telegram bot messageHandler dice value

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to use the message handler on the documentation of python-telegram-bot to retu]rn me the dice value so that I can use the value.
I'm calling the handler line 
`add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Dice, handle_dice))`

When I try to call the "handle_dice" I can't seem to be able to fetch the dice value.

I'm trying to use `value = update.message.dice.value()` and everytime I run it it give me an error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Dice.value`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.dice.html#telegram.Dice.value) is an attribute, not a method. It can not be called. Simply drop the `()`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.